# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Blog\register.php

Tags: php

I am trying this code but not getting the result, what should I have to try?

```
<?php if(count($errors) > 0): ?>
   <div class="msg error">
       <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
         <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>  
   </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That code looks like it should work. Are you sure you've only got the one `endif` in place?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to be a part of a PHP script designed to display error messages stored in an array called $errors. However, it appears that the opening tag for the PHP block is incomplete. Here's a corrected version of the code:

```
<?php if(count($errors) > 0): ?>
   <div class="msg error">
       <ul>
           <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
               <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
           <?php endforeach; ?>  
       </ul>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I added an opening `<ul>` tag to enclose the list items (`<li>`) and closed it appropriately. Also, I added `<?php endif; ?>` to close the conditional statement started with `<?php if(count($errors) > 0): ?>`.